# Duplicating/triplicating rows of data

Tags: google-sheets

I have these rows:

```
Alex
Bob
Chris
```

I need a function to create three rows for each one, in a way it looks like this:

```
Alex
Alex
Alex
Bob
Bob
Bob
Chris
Chris
Chris
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to achieve the following conversion using the built-in functions.

  - From

    ```
    Alex
    Bob
    Chris
    ```
  - To

    ```
    Alex
    Alex
    Alex
    Bob
    Bob
    Bob
    Chris
    Chris
    Chris
    ```

For this, how about this answer?

#### Sample formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("#",TRUE,SUBSTITUTE("###","#",A1:A3&"#")),"#")))
```

- The flow of above formula is as follows.

  1. Create the base 3 rows using `SUBSTITUTE("###","#",A1:A3&"#")` as a string.

     - For example, `Alex` becomes `Alex#Alex#Alex#`.
  2. Merge each string of each source rows using `TEXTJOIN`.

     - For example, `Alex, Bob, Chris` becomes `Alex#Alex#Alex##Bob#Bob#Bob##Chris#Chris#Chris#`.
  3. Split the string using `SPLIT`.

     - By this, each value is put to each cell.
  4. Transpose the values using `TRANSPOSE`.

     - By this, the result value can be retrieved.
- In this case, `=TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("#",TRUE,SUBSTITUTE("###","#",A1:A3&"#")),"#")))` can be also retrieve the same result.

#### Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- If the source values include `#`, please modify to other character.
- In this case, when a lot of rows are converted, an error related to the limitation might occur. So please be careful this.

#### References:

- [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215)
- [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992)
- [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [TRANSPOSE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262)